# Python exchangelib push notification?

Tags: exchangelib

is it possible push notification in exchangelib ?
I tried get email in inbox and trigger my function,thats is it available exchangelib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exchangelib doesn't support EWS push notifications yet, unfortunately. There's a PR open which implements some of the functionality: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/pull/355

For now, you'll have to do a regular client-side pull:

```
has_email = account.inbox.filter(subject='Some Trigger Value').exists()
```

Comment: Thank you dude :)